# Activate Django user after successful PayPal payment

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, django-signals

I am attempting to implement a PayPal gateway after user sign-up for a webapp. Once the user registration form is submitted, a signal sets the user to inactive (on purpose). I want to set the user to active after a successful PayPal payment; however, Im having trouble identifying how to get the user id to the receiver to activate the user account since the PayPal button has a separate landing page (and the user isn't authenticated at this point).

Is it possible to pass the newly created user instance from the registration page as context to the payment-process page? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code below:
VIEWS

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("process-payment")
    else:
        # create empty form for user to fill in
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, "register/register.html", {"form": form})


def payment_done(request):
    return redirect('login')


def process_payment(request):
    host = request.get_host()
    paypal_dict = {
        "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
        'business': settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "a3": "1.75",  # monthly price
        "p3": "1",  # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
        "t3": "M",  # duration unit ("M for Month")
        "src": "1",  # make payments recur
        "sra": "1",  # reattempt payment on payment error
        "no_note": "1",  # remove extra notes (optional)
        'item_name': 'subscription',
        'custom': f"{}",  # User ID passed here
        'currency_code': 'USD',
        'notify_url': f'http://{host}{reverse("paypal-ipn")}',
        'return_url': f'http://{host}{reverse("payment-done")}',
        'cancel_return': f'http://{host}{reverse("payment-cancelled")}',
    }

    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")
    return render(request, 'main/process-payment.html', {"form":form})
```

SIGNALS

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def set_user_inactive(sender, instance, created, update_fields, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.is_active = False
        instance.save()


@receiver(valid_ipn_received)
def ipn_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender

    # check for subscription signup IPN
    if ipn_obj.txn_type == "subscr_signup":

        # get user id and activate the account
        id = ipn_obj.custom
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

        subject = 'Registration Complete'

        message = 'Thanks for signing up with our appl!'

        email = EmailMessage(subject,
                             message,
                             'test123@gmail.com',
                             [user.email])

        email.send()

    # check for subscription payment IPN
    elif ipn_obj.txn_type == "subscr_payment":

        # get user id and extend the subscription
        id = ipn_obj.custom
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        user.extend()  # extend the subscription

        subject = 'Your Invoice for {} is available'.format(
            datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%b %Y"))

        message = 'Thanks for using our app. This is a reoccurring payment notification for your subscription ' \
                  'to our app. $1.75 charged to your account.'

        email = EmailMessage(subject,
                             message,
                             'test123@gmail.com',
                             [user.email])

        email.send()

    # check for failed subscription payment IPN
    elif ipn_obj.txn_type == "subscr_failed":
        pass

    # check for subscription cancellation IPN
    elif ipn_obj.txn_type == "subscr_cancel":
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
        'business': settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
```

That is a very old, [deprecated legacy integration](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/) method. Do not use it for new integrations.

See the [current PayPal Subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) documentation. You can create plans via its API calls (authenticate with a clientid and secret to obtain an access token) or in the account's web interface:

- Sandbox https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans
- Live https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans

Comment: Thanks for the response and I will look into implementing PayPal as you suggested However, I still don't see how this will pass the required info back to active the user within Django once subscription sign-up in complete. Am I missing something?

Comment: Add a `custom_id` value alongside the plan when creating the subscription and subscribe to the webhook event PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED to be notified of the first payment as well as all future payments.

Comment: In sandbox Paypal doesn't allow webhook urls that aren't https. So that eliminates that option for me while in development on localhost. Do you know if there are any other sources of documentation for PayPal's API because what is provided for python on their site is almost non-existent.

Comment: Use something like ngrok. The webhook is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the how to pass user information between view methods without* them being authenticated/active (by storing the info in session) in case anyone else runs into a similar issue:

```
def registration(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    request.session['username'] = user.username
    return redirect('next_view')

def next_view(request):
    username = request.session.get('username')
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

Now the user object can be passed around for background operations if the user isn't authenticated.